# How can I Solidify / cure silicone caulk used to create tubing?

Tags: bond

Curing and preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself
[Food Grade RTV Silicone Sealant Adhesive Clear 10.3oz](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Food-Grade-RTV-Silicone-Sealant-Adhesive-Clear-10-3oz/281064707252?_trkparms=aid%3D1110012%26algo%3DSPLICE.SOIPOST%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20201210111451%26meid%3D9ebd4e397fef4d809177cef6957f4e9e%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dpf%26sd%3D283630411208%26itm%3D281064707252%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DPromotedSellersOtherItemsV2WithMLRv3&_trksid=p2047675.c101196.m2219) when creating tubes.

Some videos show using hot water and some videos show using cold water and hydrogen peroxide [Video link on using silicone to create tubes](https://youtu.be/KlNXHEqKLdg).  Anyone know of a **more exact formula** / **ratios** most people seem to just be guessing.

**I'm not making a fuel line**

[image: image1]

**I'm not making a fuel line** but different size tubes which will be transporting **water vapour** / **mist** created using a ultrasonic transducer (used in pond foggers) to test with (testing a fogpoinc delivery system).

PS:  I know to use dark tubes to prevent algae growth in the tubes (this is just a delivery test setup).

I created / 3d printed different screw caps (extrusion molds) to create different size tubes to test with

See example:

[image: Tube creator]

**Question:**

Anyone know of a more exact formula / ratios curing and preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself while creating the tubes shown in the video?  The video shows using water and hydrogen peroxide but doesn't specify the ratios to use.

Comment: What is the question  ?

Comment: Anyone know of a more exact formula / ratios curing and preventing silicon caulk from sticking to itself while creating the tubes shown in the video.  The video shows using water and hydrogen peroxide but doesn't specify the ratios to use.

Comment: It is not a question. It is a statement.

Comment: @RickT have you figured out a ratio that works for you? I was looking for the same thing and came here after doing some research.

Comment: @mvaneijgen unfortunately no, it just keeps sticking.